# Can I use a gradient to fill an element_rect using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to have a gradient as the background of my plot.

Is this possible with ggplot2?

I'd like to be able to apply a gradient fill to any `element_rect` (not just the panel background as done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30136725/plot-background-colour-in-gradient)).

Comment: I wrote an `element_gradient` before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55372888/8449629). You may find it relevant.